# how to extract certificate from .ovpn file

Tags: openvpn, mikrotik

I'm using road warrior openvpn server. As end-point client configuration  I have .ovpn files. I want to setup openvpn client on Mikrotik 4011 router, but it seems only work with certificates and private keys.

Comment: An `.ovpn` file is plain text. Most of its contents is the configuration (for the `openvpn` binary) but it may contain several sections containing a certificate, a key (and certain other generated things)—all clearly delimited and encoded using `base64`. So I think merely opening this file with a text editor and copying the data from the relevant section from it into a separate file would do the trick. Do copy the delimiters though—OpenVPN might need them to understand what sort of data it sees.

Comment: Thank you! it contains two certificates(-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----) and one private key. Which certificate i need? i

Comment: also it contains # 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----

Comment: Re. certificates: that's tricky: one is supposedly the client's and another one is of the CA which issued the former. AFAIK it's fine to create a concatenated file containing both of them (be sure to include those `---...` things!)

Comment: Re. the static key. I beleive this is [the key for the `tls-auth` directive](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/hardening-openvpn-security/).